# How to set up HTTPS for local testing purposes?

Tags: apache, ssl, https

I need to see how a web application will work with HTTPS. But I can't really find much information around about it. I tried to set up my local Apache but I can't find a CA autorithy to sign my certificate... Hints? Suggestions?

Comment: If it’s really just for local testing purposes, the easiest is to create a self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 12):

The possibilities to consider are:

1. Generate your own certificate (self-signed certificate)
2. Get a certificate issued by a known issuer
3. Get a certificate issued by an issuer not recognised by the browser

Nr. 1 is probably the most widely used solution. You can find instructions [here](http://slacksite.com/apache/certificate.php). The only disadvantage is that browsers will complaint about the unknown CA. In Firefox, you can just add a permanent exception and get rid of the warning. (Neither Chrome nor Internet Explorer seem to provide such option.)

Nr. 2 normally costs money so it isn't a popular choice for dev environments.

Nr. 3 can be obtained for free (see https://www.cacert.org/) but they also trigger a browser warning. A difference with nr. 1 is that you have the possibility of adding the CA to your browser's trusted authorities; however, that's a serious decision that requires serious consideration because of its security implications. In general, I would not recommend it for mere testing.

Comment: Thank you for the first link, it works with some perseverance, do not forget to uncomment "LoadModule ssl_module libexec/apache2/mod_ssl.so" in httpd.conf. Safari provides the option to remember the exception through Keychain.

Answer (score 2):

Self-signed certificates (as already mentioned) are probably the easiest option for a single host.

If there are a few hosts, you could create a mini CA of your own. There are tools for this, for example:

- [CA.pl](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/CA.pl.html): a script provided with OpenSSL.
- [TinyCA](https://opsec.eu/src/tinyca/): a tool with a GUI.

Comment: Unfortunately, TinyCA is no more. The link is dead.