# HTTP Ajax Request via HTTPS Page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am having a site with some pages on HTTPS connection. From these HTTPS pages, I have to use a HTTP Ajax request for some errors retrieval like blank fields. But this error messages are not coming. Is there any solution to it or I have to make that AJAX request to file on HTTPS connection?

Comment: ajax should run fine on https, can you post your actual code snippet?

Comment: Sounds like SOP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy): the schemas are different, so it is a different origin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have changed my website accordingly.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This is not possible due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

You will need to switch the Ajax requests to https, too.

Comment: Even the working draft of Cross-Origin Resource Sharing makes it impossible: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#user-agent-security

Comment: Thanks for the answer everyone. I have changed my website according to same origin policy.

Comment: @NickSotiros Why would you not want it secure? There's zero downside, and HTTP requests on an HTTPS page could potentially be attacked by a MITM to inject malicious JS.

Comment: @ceejayoz Well if you download a js script and execute it you could be attacked by a MITM.  But if you just want to use someone else's background image in your css or download a youtube video, you can't.  Why does the browser assume that content loaded via an ajax request is going to be javascript to execute?  There is the site https://prezi.com which allows you to generate online presentations with online content pulled in from external resources, they must be using proxies.

Comment: @NickSotiros actually someones css can hook to inputs and send all data entered in those inputs to a bad server.

Comment: i have the same problem but this time my http domain is in the local domain not public,so https blocked by browser because ssl not verified,what can i do in this case

Comment: @user818117 I don't know whther it's suitable for bridging https and non-https requests, but theoretically, having your local server emit a CORS header: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourlocal.resource`. See "The Cross-Origin Resource Sharing method" in the top answer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy

Comment: @Pekka웃 my local server emits Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *; the thing is from https i cant make request to http(so i cant use as ```http://yourlocal.resource```),if i make local server https as (```https://yourlocal.resource```) this time browser complains as same as in red address bar,and blocks json request

Comment: @user818117 ah. Then you'd have to get SSL actually running on your local server. Not sure how difficult it is but here's instructions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164629/how-to-set-up-https-for-local-testing-purposes

Answer (score 16):

Without any server side solution, Theres is only one way in which a secure page can get something from a insecure page/request and that's thought postMessage and a popup

I said popup cuz the site isn't allowed to mix content. But a popup isn't really mixing. It has it's own window but are still able to communicate with the opener with postMessage.

So you can open a new http-page with `window.open(...)` and have that making the request for you

---

[XDomain](https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain) came to mind when i wrote this but here is a modern approach using the new [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), the advantage is the streaming of large files, the downside is that it won't work in all browser

You put this proxy script on any http page

```
onmessage = evt => {
  const port = evt.ports[0]

  fetch(...evt.data).then(res => {
    // the response is not clonable
    // so we make a new plain object
    const obj = {
      bodyUsed: false,
      headers: [...res.headers],
      ok: res.ok,
      redirected: res.redurected,
      status: res.status,
      statusText: res.statusText,
      type: res.type,
      url: res.url
    }

    port.postMessage(obj)

    // Pipe the request to the port (MessageChannel)
    const reader = res.body.getReader()
    const pump = () => reader.read()
    .then(({value, done}) => done 
      ? port.postMessage(done)
      : (port.postMessage(value), pump())
    )

    // start the pipe
    pump()
  })
}
```

Then you open a popup window in your https page (note that you can only do this on a user interaction event or else it will be blocked)

```
window.popup = window.open(http://.../proxy.html)
```

create your utility function

```
function xfetch(...args) {
  // tell the proxy to make the request
  const ms = new MessageChannel
  popup.postMessage(args, '*', [ms.port1])

  // Resolves when the headers comes
  return new Promise((rs, rj) => {

    // First message will resolve the Response Object
    ms.port2.onmessage = ({data}) => {
      const stream = new ReadableStream({
        start(controller) {

          // Change the onmessage to pipe the remaning request
          ms.port2.onmessage = evt => {
            if (evt.data === true) // Done?
              controller.close()
            else // enqueue the buffer to the stream
              controller.enqueue(evt.data)
          }
        }
      })

      // Construct a new response with the 
      // response headers and a stream
      rs(new Response(stream, data))
    }
  })
}
```

And make the request like you normally do with the fetch api

```
xfetch('http://httpbin.org/get')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(console.log)
```

Comment: Nice, created a module [`cors-bypass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-bypass) that does this seamlessly.

Comment: Why open a new window?  Couldn't you put the request in an iframe?

Comment: @Chiwda no, because you are mixing secure with insecure content then, using a popup isn't mixing

Comment: I finally did this in a very simple way:
                w = window.open("",'_blank', 'toolbar=no,titlebar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,left=12000, top=12000,width=10,height=10,visible=none', '');
  w.location.href = MyURI;
  setTimeout(function() {
   w.close();
  }, 6000)

Comment: @Endless; i am having issues with getting this working. I have a https page and a local wifi (192.168.4.1/proxy.html and 192.168.4.1/id). Do i place the first script "onmessage = evt => {...." on proxy.hml on my local machine? and hwere does the function `xfetch(...args) {` go? I assume that the windows.popup goes on the https page after user clicks on buton (or something), and also fires the request (xfetch)?

Answer (score 6):

Still, this can be done with the following steps:

1. send an https ajax request to your web-site (the same domain)

   ```
   jQuery.ajax({
       'url'      : '//same_domain.com/ajax_receiver.php',
       'type'     : 'get',
       'data'     : {'foo' : 'bar'},
       'success'  : function(response) {
           console.log('Successful request');
       }
   }).fail(function(xhr, err) {
       console.error('Request error');
   });
   ```
2. get ajax request, for example, by php, and make a CURL get request to any desired website via http.

   ```
   use linslin\yii2\curl;
   $curl = new curl\Curl();
   $curl->get('http://example.com');
   ```

Comment: This concept worked perfect (using code relevant to my setup/project). I created a php file on my server and did a curl request on an HTTP Url. I called this file from my HTTPS website and sent in the variable I needed for the API and voila!

Comment: I only know may endpoint, how to use this method to my website.
My website is https and API is `http://5ty.org:8080/api/card/post`

Comment: The downside is if you have many concurrent requests to your page, then you could saturate your server.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases a one-way request without a response can be fired to a TCP server, without a SSL certificate. A TCP server, in contrast to a HTTP server, will catch you request. However there will be no access to any data sent from the browser, because the browser will not send any data without a positive certificate check. And in special cases even a bare TCP signal without any data is enough to execute some tasks. For example for an IoT device within a LAN to start a connection to an external service. [Link](https://medium.com/@ebakhtarov/oneway-request-from-https-page-to-http-resource-without-errors-4927b367d77c)

This is a kind of a "Wake Up" trigger, that works on a port without any security.

In case a response is needed, this can be implemented using a secured public https server, which can send the needed data back to the browser using e.g. Websockets.

Answer (score 2):

Make a bypass API in server.js. This works for me.

```
app.post('/by-pass-api',function(req, response){
  const url = req.body.url;
  console.log("calling url", url);
  request.get(
    url,
    (error, res, body) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return response.status(200).json({'content': "error"}) 
}
        return response.status(200).json(JSON.parse(body))
        },
      )
    })
```

And call it using axios or fetch like this:

```
const options = {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
     url:`http://localhost:3000/by-pass-api`, // your environment 
     data: { url },  // your https request here
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a module called [`cors-bypass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-bypass), that allows you to do this without the need for a server. It uses [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to send cross-domain events, which is used to provide mock HTTP APIs (`fetch`, `WebSocket`, `XMLHTTPRequest` etc.).

It fundamentally does the same as the [answer by Endless](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44943661/5269570), but requires no code changes to use it.

**Example usage:**

```
import { Client, WebSocket } from 'cors-bypass'

const client = new Client()

await client.openServerInNewTab({
  serverUrl: 'http://random-domain.com/server.html',
  adapterUrl: 'https://your-site.com/adapter.html'
})

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org')
ws.onopen = () => ws.send('hello')
ws.onmessage = ({ data }) => console.log('received', data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Make a bypass API in server.js or index.js. I am using express.js library.

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'; // custom_code
import axios from 'axios'; // custom-code
let app = express();
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.post('/by-pass-api', jsonParser, async (req, response) => {
  const { url } = req.body;
  const data = { data: req.body.data };
  const result = await axios.post(url, data);
  response.send({ success: true, result: result });
});
  


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running as on port 3000`);
  });
```

Create a function to call your localhost server(your application server) using axios or fetch like this:

> url: `http://your-http-api-url` : This is external http url.

```
axios.post("http://localhost:3000/by-pass-api", {
              headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
              url: `http://your-http-api-url`,
              data: {...your_payload},
            })
```

Answer (score -1):

From the javascript I tried from several ways and I could not.

You need an server side solution, for example on c# I did create an controller that call to the http, en deserialize the object, and the result is that when I call from javascript, I'm doing an request from my https://domain to my htpps://domain. Please see my c# code:

```
[Authorize]
public class CurrencyServicesController : Controller
{
    HttpClient client;
    //GET: CurrencyServices/Consultar?url=valores?moedas=USD&alt=json
    public async Task<dynamic> Consultar(string url)
    {
        client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.promasters.net.br/cotacao/v1/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;

        var FromURL = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(FromURL);
    }
```

And let me show to you my client side (Javascript)

```
<script async>
$(document).ready(function (data) {

    var TheUrl = '@Url.Action("Consultar", "CurrencyServices")?url=valores';
    $.getJSON(TheUrl)
        .done(function (data) {
            $('#DolarQuotation').html(
                '$ ' + data.valores.USD.valor.toFixed(2) + ','
            );
            $('#EuroQuotation').html(
                '€ ' + data.valores.EUR.valor.toFixed(2) + ','
            );

            $('#ARGPesoQuotation').html(
                'Ar$ ' + data.valores.ARS.valor.toFixed(2) + ''
            );

        });       

});
```

I wish that this help you!
Greetings