# AJAX Request From HTTPS Page to HTTP Url

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, https, cors

I have a case where I need to perform an AJAX request from an HTTPS page to another one (on a different domain) that is not secure. We've already implemented CORS policy and it was working fine before using HTTPS on our website. Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Ajax Request via HTTPS Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032104/http-ajax-request-via-https-page)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to W3, it's not possible through a COR policy due to "certificate errors"
http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#user-agent-security