# Is it necessary for Server to allow/configure CORS

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, cors

I am trying to perform an AJAX request from my site which is deployed on 'HTTPS' protocol. but the request I am making to is deployed on 'HTTP' protocol.
So I am getting the following error:

> This request has been blocked; the content must be served over
>   HTTPS

My Request is as follows:

```
 $.ajax({
         url: "http://testsite/service/process.php",        
         type: "POST",
         data: { service: '@service', id: '@id' }                    
        });
```

> Is there any way/trick to bypass this error/issue without changing
>   anything at ServerSide (http://testsite/) or Is it necessary to
>   ENABLE/CONFIGURE C.O.R.S on Server Side because I have no controll over Server Side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AJAX Request From HTTPS Page to HTTP Url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703549/ajax-request-from-https-page-to-http-url)

Answer (score 1):

**Alternatives to CORS**

If your web application must run in browsers that do not support CORS or interact with servers that are not CORS-enabled, there are several alternatives to CORS that have been utilized to solve the cross-origin communication restriction.

**JSONP.** This is a technique that exploits the HTML script element exception to the same-origin security policy.  Script tags can load JavaScript from a different domain and query parameters can be added to the script URI to pass information to the server hosting the script about the resources that you wish to access. The JSONP server will return JavaScript that is evaluated in the browser that calls an agreed upon JavaScript function already on the page to pass server resource data into your page.

**OpenAjax Hub**. This is an JavaScript Ajax library that allows integration of multiple client-side components within a single web application. Trusted and untrusted components to co-exist within the same page and communicate with each other as long as they all include the OpenAjax Hub JavaScript library. The framework provides a security manager to allow the application to set security policies on component messaging. Iframes are used to isolate components into secure sandboxes.

**easyXDM.** This is a JavaScript library that allows for string-based cross domain communication via iframes.  It works on the same principals as OpenAjax Hub but does not have the security manager component.

**Proxied Iframe.** This do-it-yourself technique involves including an iframe on your page from the domain you wish to communicate with.  This assumes that you are able to host pages on this other domain.  The JavaScript running in the iframe serves as a rest proxy to the server containing the resources you wish to access.  Communication between your application and the rest proxy will take place using post message.  Post message is part of the HTML5 standard, but there is also a jQuery implementation for non HTML5-compliant browsers.