# Can we make a GET between HTTPS and HTTP site?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, https

[image]

I have a site that I hosted in Shopify in `HTTPS`, then I made a **GET** via Angular to a `HTTP` site.

---

**Angular**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900" rel="stylesheet">

<style type="text/css">
    div {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

    p, a {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

    .body-text-header-large {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        font-weight: 300;
        line-height: 2em;
        color: #42baf1;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

    .company-name {
        font-weight: 900;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

</style>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="container">


        <span class="body-text-header-large">DISTRIBUTORS</span>
        <p class="silver">Bioss Antibodies are sold worldwide. Find a distributor near you to order in your area!</p>



        <div ng-repeat="obj in data" >

            <div class="row">

                <!-- Country -->
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" >
                <p>{{obj.country}}</p>
                    <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{obj.flag}}" alt="" width="30px">
                </div>

                <!-- Main Info -->
                <div class="col-xs-4" >
                    <p class="company-name">{{obj.user.username}}</p>
                    <p>{{obj.distributor.phone_public}}</p>
                    <p>{{obj.user.email}}</p>
                    <a href="{{obj.distributor.url}}">{{obj.distributor.url}}</a></span> <span class="col span_2_of_6">
                </div>

                <!-- Logo -->
                <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right" >
                    <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{obj.logo}}" alt="" width="100px">
                </div>

            </div>

            <br><hr>


        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<script>

    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("http://d.biossusa.com/api/distributor?key=*******")
        .then(function(response) {
            var data = response.data;

            var array = $.map(data, function(value) {
                return [value];
            });

            console.log(typeof(array));
            console.log(array.length);
            console.log(array);

            try {
              $scope.data = array;
          } catch (error) {
              console.log('its not json');
          }
      });
    });

</script>
```

---

**Result locally**

work perfectly fine

[image]

---

I kept getting

> Refused to connect to 'http://d.biossusa.com/api/distributor?key=******' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' https://* wss://*".

[image]

Turning my API site from HTTP into HTTPS might be a bit expensive. What is the work around for this ?

Is there another way ?

Is there any frameworks or API that help avoid this error ?

Comment: In my NGINX configs, I already set it to allow all header from any origins. Do I still need to do anything elses  ?

Comment: What are you doing with the HTTP site?  Are you hosting it in an iFrame?  Showing a bit of example code would go a long way here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey : I updated my post with what I am trying to do. All I am trying to do it to making a GET to an API and display back the data nicely ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374373/jquery-ajax-call-from-https-to-http

Comment: @KevinB he is not using jQuery. Please take a look at the specs.

Comment: @lin the fact that the linked question uses jquery is irrelevant. jquery is javascript, and it's getting rejected for the same reason. the answer is the same, not possible.

Comment: @KevinB explain it please. Is CORS a lie?

Comment: ?? you're not making any sense.

Comment: @KevinB is the W3C standard CORS - https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/ a lie? Please explain why it should not work for HTTP/HTTPS AJAX requests.

Comment: No, of course not. It simply doesn't apply in this specific case because the direction is https -> http. If it were going in the opposite direction, CORS would apply. using cors (which the op claims to be doing already) will not solve this problem.

Comment: @KevinB yea right. I get the users graphic on the top of his question wrong. It does mean the opposite.

Comment: @lin : If you take a look at the direction of the arrow. It's from HTTPS to HTTP.

Comment: @ihue yea i know. But the arrow from HTTPS to HTTP is not marked with an `x` what in my opinion implies that it is working. Or in other words: The client running on HTTPS is able to request the HTTP side. A client running on HTTP is not abled to request the HTTPS side. I probably get that `x` wrong.

Comment: The client running on HTTPS is able to request the HTTP side ??? How do I do that ? that is **exactly** what I am trying to do.

Comment: @ihue what does the `x` stand for?

Comment: @ihue Owww, the X for working is gone. :) Glad to help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Ajax Request via HTTPS Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032104/http-ajax-request-via-https-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While calling a URL on from **HTTP to HTTPS** the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) will block your request. The browser protocol is handled as a different origin.

For example you can use [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) to enable cross-origin HTTP-Requests. Using CORLS **will allow** you to send requests **from HTTP to HTTPS**. This is a [good guide](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) which lay down the basics on using CORS and what it is.

Mostly you need to allow the cross-domain request by adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to your response header. This configuration will be made in your backend application (serverside). But this will not help you at this time:

**Note** that CORS/AJAX requests will **not work** if you call a URL **from HTTPS to HTTP** due to the security features of browsers. Take a look at the [w3c access control security](https://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/#user-agent-security) which says:

> As indicated as the first step of the cross-origin request algorithm and in the redirect steps algorithm user agents are allowed to terminate the algorithm and not make a request. This could be done because e.g.:
>
> - The origin of the resource blacklisted.
> - The origin of the resource is known to be part of an intranet.
> - The URL  is not supported.
>   -https to http is not allowed.
> - https is not allowed because of certificate errors

Comment: HTTPS making a get to HTTP ? No way around that right ?

Comment: You could use a proxy or script which run on HTTPS and forwarding your requests to your HTTP destination.

Comment: Do you have a sample or a recommend for that kind of task ?

Comment: I recommend to make your API running on HTTPS.

Comment: There is a [work around](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44943661/1008999) for https -> http

Answer (score 0):

Because of CORS policy, it's not possible to call from HTTP URL to HTTPS, I was facing the same problem.
So,  I have changed my website from HTTP to HTTPS, Use [https://www.cloudflare.com/][1]

To convert your HTTP website to HTTPS.

Comment: You are correct-ish, i just don't think the problem is related to cors specifically. It's rejected for the same reason http images are rejected on https pages.

Comment: What cloudflare do ? It turn my HTTP site into HTTPS ? Is it like an SSL site ?

Comment: Yes, it is free SSL site, So it turns your site from HTTP to HTTPS and you will not face these issue.