# AWS ELB HTTPS Port forward setting

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-ec2

When I setup the LBS on the aws, I set SSL offload to forward requests from port 443 on ELB to port 80 on the EC2 instances.

I am not sure this is right or not since I saw many people did that. But after I did that I got lots of errors within the browser console:

"This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."

Should I change the forward port 80 to 443? and install ssl for each instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

443 to 80 is correct.  Your EC2 instance serves plain data, the ELB encrypts it before sending it out of AWS.

There are a few nuances to this- the server thinks it is serving plain content on 80, so if it creates URLs they will typically be `http://` without some configuration. (it depends on your framework, server, etc)

The second nuance is that hardcoded URLs will break it in a similar manner. [That error message has been explained in a stackoverflow question about Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134098/this-request-has-been-blocked-the-content-must-be-served-over-https), some form of that is causing your problem.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I found the reason why it did not work. It is not because I hard code http:// in any ajax call, it is because the header has one "base' element which always use [http://something](http://something)

Comment: That's what I said in the second paragraph.

Comment: @jackx I am having an exact same issue. Are you referring to META base tag in HTML header? Because mine says <base href="https://www.domain.com/dir/page"> (notice HTTPS) but the AJAX still redirects to HTTP.  I totally see that ELB redirects from HTTPS to HTTP but can't figure out a way to work around this. I was also looking at deploying SSL on EC2 instances and changing to 443 ->443 redirect instead of 443->80.