# Making an AJAX call to a LocalHost, getting net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

This is the Python script I have running on Google App Engine:

```
import webapp2

form = """
<form action="/testform">
  <input name="q">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
"""

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.response.write(form)

class TestHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    q = self.request.get("q")
    self.response.out.write(q)
    print(q)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/testform', TestHandler)], 
    debug=True)
```

I'm running an AJAX on the console to see if I can get the two to talk to each other.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
})
```

However, I'm getting an error:

```
jquery.min.js:4 GET https://localhost:8080/testform?q=somethingnew1 net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I tried Googling it, but not sure what it means. Could anyone give some advice on what I'm doing wrong, and how I should go about fixing it?

Thanks!

Comment: I am pretty sure that the webserver running on your `localhost:8080` is not configured to work with SSL, thus you need to fix your URL - use `http://` instead of `https://`.

Comment: When I use `http://` I get this error: `jquery.min.js:4 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/deploying-the-application' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost:8080/testform?q=somethingnew1'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: Hm, and are you really sure you need to call **localhost** then? If yes, then according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032104/http-ajax-request-via-https-page you have to configure your local webserver to run over SSL.

Comment: If I didn't call `localhost:8080` would would I make the url be?

Comment: What should your AJAX do? Should it call that Python script? Then you need to use `https://cloud.google.com/...`. Anyway, I kind of not understand what you are trying to achieve.