# Call HTTP (non SSL/HTTPS) REST from Firebase hosted site, using XMLHttpResponse

Tags: django, firebase, https, firebase-hosting

I am trying to build a Firebase hosted page that will connect to a (Django) HTTP web service using XMLHttpRequest in the below script.

```
    <script>
  function UserAction() {
    var req = createRequest(); // defined below
    // Create the callback functions:
    var handleResponse = function (status, response) {
        alert("status " + status + " response: " + response)
    }
    var handleStateChange = function () {
        switch (req.readyState) {
          case 0 : // UNINITIALIZED
          case 1 : // LOADING
          case 2 : // LOADED
          case 3 : // INTERACTIVE
          break;
          case 4 : // COMPLETED
          alert("case 4" + req.responseType);
          handleResponse(req.status, req.responseJson);
          break;
          default: alert("error");
        }
    }

    req.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;


req.open("GET", "https://foo.org:/bar/getid/?Id=" + document.getElementById('ID').value, true);
req.send();
    function createRequest() {
  var result = null;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // FireFox, Safari, etc.
    result = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    // MSIE
    window.alert("windows");
    result = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  } 
  else {
    // No known mechanism -- consider aborting the application
    window.alert("no known mechanism");
  }
  return result;
}
}</script>
```

Using Chrome FireBase throws 404 error. Django server does not register any connection.

Using FireFox FireBase throws 404 error. But Django server throws

```
'code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('\x16\x03\x01\x00\xcc\x01\x00\x00\xc8\x03\x03\xdf\x04{\x9f\xe4\xb2\xc2ij\x8d\x14\xd5\xaa\xdcu\x14+&\xa4\xa1\xdf\xdc\xd8\x9b?\xea\xbdh\xb8')`
```

I did find this in the FireBase documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying), making me think this is not possible. But hopefully I am wrong, or there is a way to do this in development/test, but not production.

> SSL only: Firebase Hosting is SSL-only, meaning that content will only
>   be served over HTTPS. As you are developing your application make sure
>   that all external resources not hosted on Firebase Hosting are loaded
>   over SSL (HTTPS), including any external scripts. Most browsers do not
>   allow users to load "mixed content" (SSL and non-SSL traffic).

thanks

Comment: What happens if you change the "https" to an "http"?

Comment: sorry, that was just a test, but the same thing happens. thanks.

Comment: Firebase Hosting is always HTTPS, so [looks like no dice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032104/http-ajax-request-via-https-page).

Comment: I'm having the same issue, how did you solve this problem?