# Send ajax requests to localhost from a website

Tags: ajax, localhost

Can i send an Jquery/ajax request from GoogleTranslate to localhost.I use a javascript extension for adding js code to websites.
I wanted to write simple ajax request like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: "save_word="+id,
    success:function(a){    
      alert(a)
    }
})
```

But didn't know what to write int `url`

Comment: You'd write whatever your localhost URL is.

Comment: @David i get this following error error `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://translate.google.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost/Workspace/?save_word_gt=waddle'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032104/http-ajax-request-via-https-page

Comment: @David thanks for your help David.