# Calling http api from https website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I had to change my HTTP website to HTTPS because of html5 Geo-location
API restrictions.Now that API is working fine and the whole website
works fine on local-host but when it's hosted online no API gets
called and i get no data with Status: 0. I have a Node.js back-end.

> Is the reason why it's not working is because i am calling an HTTP API
>   from an HTTPS website?

If so how do i fix this the easier way and if
not than what is the case. I am calling it using angular 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is about [same origin policy](https://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy), please check detail at: [HTTP Ajax Request via HTTPS Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032104/http-ajax-request-via-https-page)