# Http request error with codeSandBox (React/Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, codesandbox

I have strange error in online IDE like CodeSandBox/StackBlitz.
I do a sample http request (with axios but with fetch or others the problem is the same) and try to print the response in the console. 
I use React for the front and node (listen port 8080) for the back,
I precise that work when I do exactly the same with create react app, using npm start (localhost:3000 and http request in `http://[public ip]:8080/coucou`)

react code here (request is in the Main.js file): 
https://codesandbox.io/s/ww28ry45pl

When I just put `http://[public ip]:8080/coucou` that work to and I have the good response from server.

Here the error returned by server in codeSandBox (captured by the catch bloc) :

> Error {stack:
>   "createError@https://ww28ry45pl.codesandbox.io/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15
>   handleError@https://ww28ry45pl.codesandbox.io/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:87:14
>   "}

I haven't found anything about this problem.

Comment: I've been having the same error. Still got no solution.

Comment: Just encountered the same problem, any news ? Is there some setting to change ?

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are making an **HTTP** call from a secure communication point (codesandbox). You can simply use/add `https` on your public **URL** and it shall work. [HTTP Ajax Request via HTTPS Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032104/http-ajax-request-via-https-page)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was calling Localhost from codesandbox in https. I solved it by Enabling CORS handling on my localhost server.

Answer (score -1):

Just try again without `http://` prefix in the URL. I solved same error :)