# Javascript Fetch - How to Fix Failed to Fetch Error (probably from making HTTP request on HTTPS site?)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, codesandbox

This is the [React app](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-waterfall-pjtr2-creative-game-pjtr2?file=/src/Components/BGContainer.js) (and code). It generates 3 random objects (from list of 500+ objects stored locally). **I want to call [IconFinder API](https://developer.iconfinder.com/reference/search) when the random objects are chosen and just display the icons then** (instead of finding 500 icons beforehand).

I'm running it on Windows 10 with Google Chrome Version 84.0.4147.89 (Official Build) (64-bit). The code is hosted on Codesandbox. **You can take a look at all the [code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-waterfall-pjtr2-creative-game-pjtr2?file=/src/Components/BGContainer.js) or just the output and Chrome dev tools [here](https://pjtr2.csb.app/)**

**Demo XHR GET request that they show in their** **[Docs](https://developer.iconfinder.com/reference/search)**

```
var data = null;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
    console.log(this.responseText);
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://api.iconfinder.com/v4/icons/search?query=arrow&count=10");
xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Bearer <API KEY HERE>");

xhr.send(data);
```

**My Fetch GET request**

```
let url = "https://api.iconfinder.com/v4/icons/search?query=arrow&count=1&premium=0";
let h = new Headers();
h.append("Accept", "application/json");
h.append(
  "authorization",
  "Bearer <API KEY HERE>"
);
let req = new Request(url, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: h,
  credentials: "include"
});

fetch(req)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response;
    } else {
      throw Error(`Request rejected with status ${response.status}`);
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(err => console.error("Error: ", err.message));
```

**Output:** Console reads `Error: Failed to fetch`

In the Chrome Dev Tools, **Network Tab (Screenshot 1)** I see a file of type **fetch (Screenshot 2)** and file of type **json (Screenshot 3 and 4)** have something wrong with them.

**What I've tried**

- Fetch GET requests work for Codesandbox with the [Star Wars API](https://swapi.dev/) (no authentication required), but not for [MovieDB API](https://www.themoviedb.org/) (authentication in url not headers - ex. `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movi?api_key=<INSERT KEY>?<other parameters here>` ). It threw an error because `response.ok` wasn't true.
- I tried fetching data from the IconFinder API and the MovieDB API on other online IDEs (like Scrimba.com and repl.it). Those also didn't work.
- I've tried using XHR requests and fetch await requests instead of fetch requests chained with then promises on different platforms. No luck.
- I've double-checked how to set the authentication headers with the IconFinder API documentation.
- I've also double-checked that my API key is registered to the url I'm calling it from and not restricted to any domains **(Screenshot 5)**
- Looked through these Forums: **it looks like I have something going wrong with making fetch requests from a HTTPS page, but I'm not sure what I need to change in my code based on that information.** I've tried reloading the page on Codesandbox as http, but it redirects me to https automatically ([Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032104/http-ajax-request-via-https-page), [Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51812727/http-request-error-with-codesandbox-react-node), [Source 3](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10404), [Source 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed))

**This is my first time making API calls** so I don't really know what the possibilities are for what could go wrong and how to fix it. I've tried looking at some other StackOverflow threads but I'm having a hard time understanding them. Next, I'm going to try transferring the React App to a local file and seeing if I can make fetch requests there. **Anyone have any thoughts on what else I should try?**

Comment: [Screenshot 1](https://ibb.co/0mjtXc0) - Network tab files

[Screenshot 2](https://ibb.co/GtHBTVT) - Fetch file headers

[Screenshot 3](https://ibb.co/yWd0f7p) - Json file response headers

[Screenshot 4](https://ibb.co/3fLsYQw) - Json file request headers

[Screenshot 5](https://ibb.co/64kGgPg) - API configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was based on a CORS error. A friend of mine told me to test the api call to:

```
https://api.iconfinder.com/v4/icons/search?query=arrow&count=1&premium=0
```

via https://reqbin.com/. It worked on the testing website.

Then, he told me to just make the request to that url with this [Cors Anywhere tool](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/). Like this:

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.iconfinder.com/v4/icons/search?query=arrow&count=1&premium=0
```

That worked on my local development environment. Still not sure exactly HOW it works.