# Having issues fetching in Codesandbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, openweathermap

I am writing my code in codesandbox and very simply trying to fetch a weather API. I have done numerous API calls in codesandbox and it has always been just fine, except this one.

I ran it in a console and it returns the data just fine too. I seriously cannot understand what is causing this? If someone could take a look and help, that would be super appreciated. Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const WeekContainer = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  async function getData() {
    const weatherURL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=11102&units=imperial&APPID=dcadf332823cddfb979926a1414274e8`;
    const result = await fetch(weatherURL);
    const a = await result.json();
    console.log(a)
    setData(a)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return <div>weekcontainer</div>;
};

export default WeekContainer;
```

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: @ClaireLin The other person said it is because I use http instead of https. Facepalm hahaha such a tiny mistake. Thank you though!

Answer (score 3):

Your code is giving below error -

`The page at 'https://codesandbox.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=11102&units=imperial&APPID=dcadf332823cddfb979926a1414274e8'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

This is because we cannot access HTTP content from a HTTPS Page. 
Check this - [HTTP Ajax Request via HTTPS Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032104/http-ajax-request-via-https-page).

You are trying to fetch data from codesandbox which is running on HTTPS and making call to api.openweathermap.org over http. Change API request to  `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=11102&units=imperial&APPID=dcadf332823cddfb979926a1414274e8` and you should be able to fetch the data.

Here is the codesandbox for the same - https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-hopper-k5s52

Comment: Thank you @Arpitha. Cant believe it is only because of http instead of https. Anyway how/where did you get that error? I keep getting "Could not consume error" in codesandbox.

Comment: I could see that error in chrome console.