# How to can http services from https server

Tags: http, ssl, https

I have apache server(Frontend code) running on 80 port with https secure(SSL is configured). Backend server is nodejs and it is configured on 3000 port. When I tried to call services from https to http i.e. Apache(port 80 ssl configured) to Nodejs (port 3000 non-ssl) it is giving showing failed with status as "net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".

Answer (score 0):

This may have something to do with Same Origin policy.
Please see that answer: [HTTP Ajax Request via HTTPS Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032104/http-ajax-request-via-https-page).