# How to run sample Threejs VR project using local server?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to run sample threejs project for VR using xampp local server in Samsung NOTE 4 device.In this phone, online threejs VR examples(https://threejs.org/examples/?q=vr#webvr_cubes) working fine,

but same example in our local server link(http://192.168.1.2/three.js-dev/examples/?q=vr#webvr_cubes) always returns "Your browser does not support WebVR".

Can any one give me suggestions or idea how to run that sample project using xampp local server

Thanks in Advance

Comment: [Did you ask the question here too](http://answers.elteacher.info/questions/post/1938642/how-to-run-sample-threejs-vr-project-using-local-server-ask-question.html), or was this scraped from Stack Overflow? Asking the same question in multiple locations may seem like a good way to expand your resources, but if you get an answer in one place, the other place will likely never get updated.

Comment: This person had the same problem not too long ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44976987/three-js-webvr-example-code-works-on-threejs-org-but-not-on-my-local-server/45244843

Answer (score 2):

At this time, WebVR is still an experimental feature (I assume you're using Chrome).

http://192.168.1.2/ is not seen as a trusted entity, hence experimental features are disabled.
However http://127.0.0.1 and https://threejs.org are allowed to use this feature.

To enable WebVR, go to `chrome://flags/#enable-webvr` and click Enable

---

If you want your users to be able to use WebVR today, you have to apply for [Origin Trials](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/OriginTrials/blob/gh-pages/developer-guide.md) by filling in this [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfO0_ptFl8r8G0UFhT0xhV17eabG-erUWBDiKSRDTqEZ_9ULQ/viewform).
Google will give you a token to add on your page. (Note that you will have to set up HTTPS on your server).

Alternatively, you can add a [polyfill](https://github.com/googlevr/webvr-polyfill) to make your VR work everywhere (not just in Chrome M59+).
(just include the polyfill before three.js)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I followed same solution, now it is working fine.